# Excel - Trimmeans alternative

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to run a trimmean function on a set of data, and it needs to be based on multiple input items.

The raw data has an average range, and 3 columns for criteria matching (Month, and two more group fields Match1 and Match2).

I am unable to get this to work, even using an array formula and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I would like to use trimmean to remove 10% of the outlying record set.
Any advice?
I attached a sample sheet.

The formula I have now is  `=TRIMMEAN(IF(team=$A2,IF(ISNUMBER(range),range)),0.1)`

[Click here for file sample](http://www.filedropper.com/trimmeantest)

Comment: please include sample dataset in your question instead of linking to the file itself, people don't like opening files from random sites. Also please describe what unable to get to work means, do you get error? If yes what?

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula is not complete, for example if range is not number which value you want??
=TRIMMEAN(IF(team=$A2,IF(ISNUMBER(range),range,)),0.1) the comma after range is missing in your formula (the value if isnumber(range) is false